# Price Calculation Tool

Tags: javascript, math, calculator

I'm trying to make a tool for a price calculation. The reduction on some of the options is a bit complicated and i'm stuck on how to translate this to code. 
There are 4 different products:
Product 1: €10
Product 2: €20
Product 3: €30
Product 4: €40

For Product 1 and Product 2 there is no reduction.

If you buy 2 or more of Product 3, the price reduces to €21.

If you buy 2 or more of Product 4, the price reduces to €31.

If you buy Product 3 and Product 4 together, the price reduces to €21 and €31 for the products respectively.

Can you guys help me out on how I should go about translating this to javascript (or another language if you think there's a better solution)?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Make a JSON object with all the products as keys and the counts of the products should be stored as corresponding values. Apply the rules and get the values according to them. return the total

Comment: What happens if, in the future, product 1 will get a discount? My question is actually, how will you, as a frontend programmer, know product 1 is product 1?

Comment: give all the products a unique id for identification. Store it in a map. At the time of billing apply the discounts

Answer (score 1):

You can create a relation for product and price Object/Map

When calculating the basket price update the product prices as per defined rules.

```js
let products = {
 p1: 10,
 p2: 20,
 p3: 30,
 p4: 40
}

let priceCalculate = (basket) => {
 let disPrices = { ...products }
 if (basket.filter(e => e === 'p3').length >= 2) disPrices.p3 = 21
 if (basket.filter(e => e === 'p4').length >= 2) disPrices.p4 = 31
 if (basket.includes('p3') && basket.includes('p4')) disPrices.p3 = 21, disPrices.p4 = 31
 return basket.reduce((a, b) => a + disPrices[b], 0);
}
let Mybasket = ['p1', 'p2', 'p3', 'p2', 'p3'];
console.log(priceCalculate(Mybasket))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use objects to store prices and values

```js
var obj={P1:10,P2:20,P3:30,P4:40};
var basket={P1:5,P2:4,P3:3,P4:8};
var total=0;
obj['P3']>=2?obj['P3']=21:false;
obj['P4']>=2?obj['P4']=31:false;
if(obj['P3']>=1 && obj['P4']>=1)
{
obj['P3']=21;
obj['P4']=31;
}
Object.keys(basket).forEach(e=>{
total+=basket[e]*obj[e];
})
console.log(total)
```

```html
Product 1: €10 Product 2: €20 Product 3: €30 Product 4: €40

For Product 1 and Product 2 there is no reduction.

If you buy 2 or more of Product 3, the price reduces to €21.

If you buy 2 or more of Product 4, the price reduces to €31.

If you buy Product 3 and Product 4 together, the price reduces to €21 and €31 for the products respectively.
```